# Create a timer within a spark context

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, bigdata

We have a spark application that streams from Kafka, and consume customer activity. I am trying to determine if a customer has stopped being active on our system for 3 minutes, (i.e. not received another transaction for this customer for 3 minutes).

I'm not sure if I am trying to implement this the right way, or if it doesn't make sense to have this logic in Spark, but I am trying to use the RecurringTimer class to do this. Has anybody implemented something similar, and if so what utility function was used in the spark libraries?

Any example, pointers etc. would also be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `mapWithState`, basically you would aggregate into a key/value pair consisting of some identifier for the customer and the timestamp of the last transaction received.

Each micro batch after performing this aggregation, you can check and see if there is any user in there that has a `timestamp < now() - 3min` and do something (i.e. push a message into another kafka queue etc)

A sample on `mapWithState` is available [here](https://docs.cloud.databricks.com/docs/spark/1.6/examples/Streaming%20mapWithState.html)

Comment: If you read this blog post, https://databricks.com/blog/2016/02/01/faster-stateful-stream-processing-in-spark-streaming.html, there's even a session timeout function described.